# Ideal determined by completions

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, p-adic-number-theory, local-rings

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an order in a number field $K$.

**Question**: Is specifying an invertible ideal $I$ of $\mathcal{O}$ equivalent to specifying invertible ideals $I_p$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathcal{O}$ for each prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$, where $I_p$ is the unit ideal for all but finitely many primes $p$?

**Partial Answer**: If $\mathcal{O} = \mathcal{O}_K$ is the ring of integers, then the answer is yes by the unique factorization of ideals in Dedekind domains. Otherwise, it is known (see Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory*, Proposition 12.6) that specifying an invertible ideal $I$ of $\mathcal{O}$ is equivalent to specifying invertible ideals $I_{\mathfrak{p}}$ of the completion $\mathcal{O}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ for each nonzero prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $\mathcal{O}$. So it is equivalent to answer the following:

**Question$'$**: Let $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ be a prime, and let $S$ be the set of nonzero prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}$ lying above $p$. Is specifying an invertible ideal $I_p$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathcal{O}$ equivalent to specifying invertible ideals $I_{\mathfrak{p}}$ of the completion $\mathcal{O}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ for each prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \in S$?

I guess answering Question$'$ boils down to understanding the relationship between the rings $\mathcal{O}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ for $\mathfrak{p} \in S$ and the ring $\mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathcal{O}$, but it's not clear to me whether this relationship admits a simple description that works for any order in any number field.

Comment: The answer to your Question’ is “yes” (which is also implied by the same Prop 12.6).